# How to use pip with python 3.4 on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Just installed a fresh copy of python 3.4.1 on windows 7. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html) says that pip is included by default. but i could not find any pip.exe or some pip commands. Do I need to install it separately or it exists somewhere?

Comment: Yes on windows 7 you can use `py -m pip install xxx` that works.

Comment: `py -m pip install` gives me: `C:\Python34\python.exe: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and can not be directly executed`

Comment: There is an open bug report:
http://bugs.python.org/issue22028

Answer (score 52):

i have Windows7  Python 3.4.1; following command suggested  by Guss worked well

```
C:\Users>py -m pip install requests
```

Output

```
Downloading/unpacking requests
Installing collected packages: requests
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you don't have any other Python installations, you should be able to do `python -m pip` after a default installation. Something like the following should be in your system path:

`C:\Python34\Scripts`

This would obviously be different, if you installed Python in a different location.

Comment: I also intalled python341 on windows 7. `python -m pip` says `no module named pip` I also see no folder `c:\python34\scripts`

Comment: There is no Scripts subdirectory. There is one under `Python34\Tools\Scripts`, but does not contain `pip`, `pip3` or `pip3.4`. Or anything starting with `pip`.

Answer (score 7):

"On Windows and Mac OS X, the CPython installers now default to installing pip along with CPython itself (users may opt out of installing it during the installation process). Window users will need to opt in to the automatic PATH modifications to have pip available from the command line by default, otherwise it can still be accessed through the Python launcher for Windows as py -m pip."

Have you tried it?

Answer (score 6):

From the [same page](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#bootstrapping-pip-by-default)

> **Note:** To avoid conflicts between parallel Python 2 and Python 3 installations, only the versioned pip3 and pip3.4 commands are bootstrapped by default when ensurepip is invoked directly - the --default-pip option is needed to also request the unversioned pip command. pyvenv and the Windows installer ensure that the unqualified pip command is made available in those environments, and pip can always be invoked via the -m switch rather than directly to avoid ambiguity on systems with multiple Python installations.

So try `pip3` or `pip3.4` in Command Prompt.

Also, ensure that environment variable are set for pip command, if you missed to opt-in for automatic `PATH` configuration.

Answer (score 3):

## Usage of `pip` for installation of packages in Python 3

**Step 1:** Install Python 3. Yes, by default an application file `pip3.exe` is already located there in the path (`E.g.`):

`C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts`

**Step 2:** Go to

```
>Control Panel (Local Machine) > System > Advanced system settings >

>Click on `Environment Variables` >
Set a New User Variable, for this click `New` >
Write new 'Variable name' as "PYTHON_SCRIPTS" >
Copy that path of `pip3.exe` and paste within variable value > `OK` >

>Below again find out and click on `Path` under 'system variables' >
Edit this path >
Within 'Variable value' append and paste the same path of `pip3.exe` after putting a ';' >
Click `OK`/`Apply` and come out.
```

**Step 3:** Now, open `cmd` bash/shell by  Pressing key `Windows+R`.

```
> Write 'pip3' and press 'Enter'. If pip3 is recognized you can go ahead.
```

**Step 4:** In this same `cmd`

```
> Write path of the `pip3.exe` followed by `/pip install 'package name'`
```

As Example just write:

`C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts/pip install matplotlib`

Press `Enter` now. The Package `matplotlib` will start getting downloaded.

**Further, for upgrading any package**

Open `cmd` bash/shell again, then

> type that path of `pip3.exe` followed by `/pip install --upgrade 'package name'`
> Press `Enter`.

As Example just write:

`C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts/pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Upgrading of the package will start
`:)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is that pip install tries to use C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Temp to unpack. You have to explicitly set those directories to R/W.I still couldn't do it because it was a work laptop and there were some permissions issues with trying to set these directories to R/W. The alternative is to go to your Env Variables, and set both Tmp and Temp to point to a writeable directory such as C:.  The installation went fine. I was able to install pip.

The way I stumbled onto this is by not defaulting pip install in my installation. Even though the pip install was failing, the installer was not giving any errors. Removing pip and then trying to manually add it later is what pointed to what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

"py -m pip install requests" works fine with Windows and its up gradation. 
Just change the path after installing Python 3.4 in the command prompt and type in "py -m pip install requests"command prompt. [pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZA6U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I install python3.5.3. And finally I find the pip.exe in this folder: ~/python/scripts/pip.exe. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old topic, but in case someone needs it

there is no `pip` in python 3.4, so we have to use `python -m ensurepip` to install `pip`