# RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required while doing any kind of PIP operation

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am new to python, started to learn a week ago. I installed Python 3.4.
Installed Eclipse and Pydev and configured the environment.
My current task is to communicate to an instrument, I downloaded python wrapper from the instrument manufacturer website and tried running in eclipse.
Soon I got error which informed packages missing.

I approached my colleague and he informed me to do PIP install, I started doing it seeing videos in YouTube and meanwhile what I did I don't remember,
Now I am unable to execute simple PIP command.
Everytime I am getting runtime error python 3.5 or later is required.

I tried downgrading the PIP version without knowing what is the current version (current version I assume is not supported in python 3.4- cannot check as none of the pip commands work)

With this situation how to ensure I can get rid of runtime error ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SohVz.png)

Comment: Python 3.4 reached end-of-life status over 3 years ago, and stopped receiving security updates over 18 months ago. There's no reason for you to be starting with such an old version of Python. Python 3.9 is the most recent version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pip with python 3.4 on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285508/how-to-use-pip-with-python-3-4-on-windows)